# AWS CLI nuances

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy MongoDB cluster using AWS CLI.

As a  template I've used [MongoDB-VPC.template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/templates/MongoDB-VPC.template), which is  provided with several variants of replica set members and shard options. Everything is deploying just fine, if I'm using AWS GUI, but  when I'm trying  to deploy VIA CLI, I'm getting  NAT instance + Prime only.

Below you can see my prompt.

The question is how to specify quantity of replicaSet members, two or more.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name i --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/templates/MongoDB-VPC.template --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=some-key  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters for the script like you send it via the form on the webUI:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack 
--stack-name i 
--template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/templates/MongoDB-VPC.template 
--parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=some-key  
ParameterKey=ClusterReplicaSetCount,ParameterValue=4  
ParameterKey=ClusterReplicaSetCount,ParameterValue=4  
ParameterKey=ClusterReplicaSetCount,ParameterValue=4  
ParameterKey=ClusterReplicaSetCount,ParameterValue=4 
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

(Obviously, set it only once, just showed where can you set up the other input parameters for the CloudFormation Script)

(The script is one line. Made it multi line for better readability.)

Source: 
[Passing Parameters to CloudFormation Stacks with the AWS CLI and Powershell](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1A23GYVMVFKFD/Passing-Parameters-to-CloudFormation-Stacks-with-the-AWS-CLI-and-Powershell)